# If I run it on laravel localhost, it shows me only file, how to fix it

Tags: laravel, localhost

If I run laravel on localhost, it shows me only file, how to fix this [image]

Comment: The document root of a laravel application is the public folder. use `php artisan serve` and it will show you a url where you can open the app

Comment: It looks like some of your files (`.env` etc.) are missing. Make sure to include hidden files when compressing files on the server.

Comment: @SemihSAHIN Files starting with `.` don't necessarily show up in Apache's file list. It's not necessarily missing.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah! I doubted that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web server such as Apache or Nginx to serve your laravel applications. If you have PHP 5.4+ and would like to use PHP's built in development server you may use the `serve` artisan command:

```
 cd /project_directory
 php artisan serve
```

By Default it will run application on port `8000`

If you want to change to other port specify port number like

```
 php artisan serve --port=8080
```

It will run your application on the PHP development server on `localhost:8080`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#local-development-environment

Comment: There are many ways to run Laravel locally.

Comment: This is the optimal way of serving laravel.  See https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#local-development-environment

Comment: That documentation is five versions old. The currently recommended approach is to use Docker, via Sail. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#laravel-and-docker

Comment: I downvoted because "To Run any Laravel Project in local environment you need to run artisan command" is inaccurate. You don't **need** to do that, it's not the only way, and it's no longer the **recommended** way either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249415/discussion-between-leena-patel-and-ceejayoz).

Answer (score 0):

The main `index.php` file is in Laravel's `public/` directory. If you visit `http://localhost/Employee/public`, you'll likely see your Laravel site.

If you point your webserver's `DocumentRoot` at that directory, you'll be able to visit the app at `http://localhost/`. If you want to run multiple apps locally, you'll want to start playing with virtualhosts.

Alternatively, consider using Laravel's Valet, Sail, or Homestead options for local development; each will handle this sort of thing for you. [Sail is Laravel's current recommendation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#laravel-and-docker).